# Faunadb after returning the same entries as the original ones

Tags: vue.js, pagination, facebook-fql, faunadb

I am creating a pagination on scroll using faunadb and vuejs. To achieve the pagination, I am passing the ref of the last entry from the original response, and doing a query using after, For some reason I am still getting the same response as the origin array. It is important to mention that my initial query is a reverse query based on the time stamp property, as to get the latest items first. I do not think this should cause an issue, Any advise is welcomed. My initial query, does not have an after field.

```
await client.query(
    q.Map(
      q.Paginate(
        q.Match(q.Index("school_query_reverse")),
        {
          after: [q.Ref(q.Collection("school_queries"), params.params.id)],
          size: 100
        }
      ),
      q.Lambda([
        'ts',
        'ref'
      ],
        q.Get(q.Var("ref"))
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: If there is no `after` field in the response from the initial query, there are no additional values that can be paginated.

Comment: Also, the `after` field in a pagination response points to the item at the start of the next page, not to the last item of the current page.

Comment: You might find the pagination tutorial to be helpful: https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/indexes/pagination

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question which I already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63694923/faunadb-how-do-i-paginate-an-index-sorted-by-timestamp). Would you consider editing that one instead of opening a new one with extra information to keep Stack Overflow organized?

Given that your index contains two values (ts and ref) which I can derive from your lambda and from your previous question, this after syntax will not work. You will have to specify at least three values. Such a cursor will look like this:

```js
  after: [
      1599220462170000,
      Ref(Collection("school_queries"), "275735235372515847"),
      Ref(Collection("school_queries"), "275735235372515847")
    ]
```

You might wonder why there are three values in there. That's because the index contains your reference and the reference is **always** added to the cursor. Using it again in the index results in it being added twice. Why and/or whether we can't optimise I can't tell but that's just how it works currently :).

If I adapt the after in your query, that'll become something like:

```js
 after: [
    1599220462170000,
    q.Ref(q.Collection("school_queries"), params.params.id)
    q.Ref(q.Collection("school_queries"), params.params.id)
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to continue paginating I added the following after: [1599220462170000], this will continue to sort from this after timestamp.